# TLS handshake with a smartcard fails randomly

Tags: .net, sockets, ssl, smartcard

I have a Windows Service which periodically connects to a host using the .NET Socket class. It's a standard TCP/IP Connection using the SMTP protocol.

The Connection is secured with a certificate that is stored on the Smartcard. I'm using the SslStream class to handle the SSL stuff.

This works most of the time. But at a random Point of time, the authentication Fails. I get this error:

```
A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.
Error type:
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException
Server stack trace: 
at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
```

Inner exception:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
The Local Security Authority cannot be contacted
```

After that failed attempt, the AuthenticationExcpetion remains, but the inner exception changes:

```
A signature operation must be performed before the user can authenticate
```

At this Point I have to restart the Service and it will now connect flawlessly. SSL handshakes will work for some time (sometimes several days) before the error occurs again.

Comment: Have you found solution for this issue by any chance? We have a similar problem. So far only restart of WCF client process helps.